# C# Regex Issues?

Tags: c#, regex, expression, notepad++

I'm using regular expressions in C# to clean up a horribly formatted .csv file. These regular expressions are:

```
text = text.Replace("\n", "");
text = text.Replace("\t", "");       
text = new Regex("([a-z,A-Z,0-9])$\r").Replace(text, "$1 ");
text = new Regex("([a-z,A-Z,0-9]) ").Replace(text, "");
text = new Regex(" $\r").Replace(text, "");
text = new Regex("([,.]$\r)").Replace(text, "");
```

These regular expressions work perfectly within Notepad++ to detect the offending strings and replace them with blank spaces. However, once I use them in C#, major errors with the formatting are still present. I assume that I'm missing something about the way regex works in C#. Please advise.

Comment: Are you escaping your \'s or using the `@` sign on your strings?

Comment: Can you show us how you are using it in the C# code? A snippet of code would make it easier to answer you.

Comment: @Walker added. but some of the Regexs are redundant because I thought I was being silly.

Comment: It's very hard to help you without any examples of sample input, expected output and actual output. Ideally, work out exactly which of your regular expressions is not doing what you expect, and provide a short but complete program demonstrating that. Until you do, this question is too vague to answer.

Comment: @RyanJ could you clarify? I was originally using the \\s to describe whitespace, but I found that I was specifically looking for spaces in that instance, so I just used a literal space.

Answer (score 2):

Your string literals are most likely not what you think they are.  In C#, there are escapse sequences that start with `\` and you want "Verbatim string literals" which are prefixed with the `@` to avoid these.

```
string s1 = "ham\n"; // Ends with a newline because of escape sequence.
string s2 = @"ham\n"; // Properly ends with \n because ampersand indicates verbatim
```

You can read about it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Note that that's an ancient link. I would have replaced it with a modern one if I had found an exact equivalent.